# AppEngine Java project in Eclipse - which jars to include?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am building some small Java application to run on Goole AppEngine.

It is not clear to how should I configure eclipse so I'll be able to compile my project but I won't deploy stuff that already exists in on the platform.
(I've tried to read about the subject - [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721547/including-required-jars-in-project) - but stil. it is not clear to me).

For example:

- The Jersey and the Junit jars - I want them to be uploaded with my code to the cloud in the deployment process.
- The AppEngine jars -I need them only for my design time - to be able to write code that is using the platform classes, but I don't want to upload them in the deployment process as they will be available to me by the platform.

Please help to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read a bit from here [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html)

And also get the plugin from there, in addition , add the Jersy and the Junit (check first that the API's are on the WillItPlayInJava list) to the build path of the project

[WillItPlayInJava](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava)

Comment: I will do that, but you should know that I am using the AppEngine plugin for Eclipse. My question still exists.

Comment: Right click the project -> Google -> Deploy to App Engine ... this will handle the whole upload for you... And Will uploaded the needed jars too... All you have to do is to add the Jersy and the Junit jars  to the build path (you need help in that?)

Comment: I know that. My problem is that I don't want to upload things that I shouldn't. this will make my upload process to be match faster (AppEngine jars can by somethings like 20MB).

Comment: OK, as far as i remember, each application that is being uploaded top GAE should come with its current GAE jars, so even if you work on 1.4.2 version and the 1.6 is out right now, your 1.4.2 app will work fine (cause its got all its jars with it), and anyway i think that eclipse wont upload all the GAE jars each time you upgrade your application